# How to find assemblies referenced directly, not via Nuget

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I have tens of projects in the solution. The projects have a lot of dependencies on 3rd party libraries. It happened that some of these libraries are referenced directly to dll file instead of using NuGet package manager. There's a couple problem with it (build, updates, etc). I want to find all such libraries that are referenced directly. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `<ItemGroup> 
     <Reference Include...`
Section of the `csproj` project file - this should list all the references used by the project and at least give you a list.

You could also look at [processExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

This will show the assemblies loaded by your application at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know about <ItemGroup><Reference> section. But these references could point to files in Nuget's "..\packages\.." directly, without listing them in packages.config.